# Android 7.1 App shortcuts : Couldn't start activity

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat

I keep getting errors when I am trying to implement the fairly new static app shortcuts from API 25.

I made an example app where the shortcuts are working as expected but when I try to implement them in my own app I keep getting the following error:

> 04-19 12:41:06.846 1623-2104/system_process E/LauncherAppsService:
>   Couldn't start activity, code=-2 04-19 12:41:06.850
>   2090-2090/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/Launcher: Unable to
>   launch. tag=DeepShortcutsContainer$UnbadgedShortcutInfo(id=-1 type=6
>   container=-1 screen=-1 cellX=-1 cellY=-1 spanX=1 spanY=1 minSpanX=1
>   minSpanY=1 rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Declaratie) intent=Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[com.android.launcher3.DEEP_SHORTCUT] flg=0x10200000
>   pkg=com.company.myapp.debug
>   cmp=com.company.myapp.debug/com.company.myapp.controllers.activity.LoginActivity
>   bnds=[477,516][1023,642] (has extras) }
>                                                                                  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Shortcut could not be
>   started
>                                                                                      at
>   android.content.pm.LauncherApps.startShortcut(LauncherApps.java:751)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.content.pm.LauncherApps.startShortcut(LauncherApps.java:717)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.launcher3.shortcuts.DeepShortcutManager.startShortcut(SourceFile:142)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.launcher3.Launcher.startShortcutIntentSafely(SourceFile:2752)
>                                                                                      at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.startActivitySafely(SourceFile:2841)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.launcher3.Launcher.startAppShortcutOrInfoActivity(SourceFile:2594)
>                                                                                      at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.onClickAppShortcut(SourceFile:2585)
>                                                                                      at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.onClick(SourceFile:2406)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.launcher3.shortcuts.DeepShortcutTextView.performClick(SourceFile:81)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

I think that the problem has something to do with my package structure.
Below is my manifest and shortcuts xml.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:name=".ApplicationEx"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.activity.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts"/>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.activity.DashboardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.activity.DeclarationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.activity.CapturePickPhotoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.activity.ProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

shortcuts.xml :

```
<shortcuts
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="declaration"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_short_label_declaration"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_long_label_declaration"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/shortcut_disabled_message">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.company.myapp"
            android:targetClass="com.company.myapp.controllers.activity.LoginActivity" />
        <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
             here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
             they launch this shortcut. -->
    </shortcut>
    <!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
</shortcuts>
```

Comment: In your `shortcuts.xml`, try changing `android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"` to `android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"`. This way, you match your `<intent-filter>`. Beyond that, is there more to the stack trace, such as one or more "Caused by" sections?

Comment: I think this line missing in your code <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" /> in shortcuts.xml file

Comment: I have tried to change the action to action.VIEW but is doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @WiebeSteverink are your shortcuts static or dynamic??

Comment: They are static, I will edit my post.

Comment: could "android:exported="true"" in the activity entry in the manifest help?

Answer (score 3):

Crash log shows package name as "com.company.myapp.debug". I think your build.gradle contains applicationId + ".debug" in "productFlavors" section. In this case, you need to change productFlavors or shortcuts.xml.

```
<shortcuts
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="declaration"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_short_label_declaration"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_long_label_declaration"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/shortcut_disabled_message">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.company.myapp.debug"
            android:targetClass="com.company.myapp.controllers.activity.LoginActivity" />
            <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
                 here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
                 they launch this shortcut. -->
    </shortcut>
    <!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
</shortcuts>
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't crashing, but my shortcut was opening the wrong activity (it was launching the other app - the one without suffix)

Answer (score 0):

```
<shortcuts
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="declaration"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_short_label_declaration"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_long_label_declaration"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/shortcut_disabled_message">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.company.myapp"
            android:targetClass="com.company.myapp.controllers.activity.LoginActivity" />
        <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
             here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
             they launch this shortcut. -->
             <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
    </shortcut>
    <!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
</shortcuts>
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything and the categorie name is not mandatory as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
  android:name="com.***.Splash"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
    android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```